# Angular 8 to 9 upgrade warnings when building

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9

I have an angular project that has multiple applications (app, dev, etc.) and I have recently upgraded it from Angular v8.2.3 to 9, and have now started to get many of the follwing warnings (about different components, this is just one example)

```
WARNING in {PATH_TO_PROJECT}\src\modules\dev\create-member\create-member.component.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
```

root ts config:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        // tslint bug isn't checking for no unused imports, their solution is to add this
        // https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/70#issuecomment-241041929
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            {"name": "@angular/language-service"}
        ]
    }
}
```

/src tsconfig:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "module": "es2015",
      "types": []
    }
}
```

I did manage to get everything to work without these warnings by adding a separate tsconfig under each application with the following contents:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "files": [
        "./{APP_NAME}.main.ts",
        "../../polyfills.ts"
    ]
}
```

Everything seemed to be building just fine with ng build --project app but when I add the --prod flag, I get a bunch of template errors about components not being recognized
E.g.

```
ERROR in src/modules/app/organizations/organization-data-budget-change/organization-data-budget-change.component.html:4:7 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
[1]
[1] 4 <form [formGroup]="DataBudgetChangeForm" class="card-body" novalidate>
[1]         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[1]
[1]   src/modules/app/organizations/organization-data-budget-change/organization-data-budget-change.component.ts:11:15
[1]     11  templateUrl: 'organization-data-budget-change.component.html'
[1]                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[1]     Error occurs in the template of component OrganizationDataBudgetChangeComponent.
```

Essentially i'm just trying to get rid of the warnings mentioned above, and i'm not sure if this is an angular issue or if my config is incorrect

UPDATE:
It seems that with the tsconfig additions mentioned above, setting aot to false in my angular.json file causes everything to work normally (Not really a fix as I do still want to use aot going forward). Same thing for disabling ivy

Comment: Were there any errors during upgrade? Did you have to use --force?

Comment: I didn't have to use --force and saw no errors.

Comment: running into the same issue here; it seems this is an issue with projects created before NG9 that are being upgraded to NG9? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a few errors after following the instructions on the upgrade page. So I deleted the node_modules, cleaned the npm cache and installed again.

These commands assume you are using npm.

```
rd /q /s node_modules (or equivalent command on your platform)
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli (optional if it already latest)
del package-lock.json (or equivalent command 
on your platform)
npm install
ng add @angular/localize (in case it was not already added)
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli
```

Comment: Ran through above commands, still getting the same warnings; i'm not sure if it is an issue with any angular code, rather an issue with my specific config

Comment: when you build, are there old files lingering in the dist folder? I delete files in that folder before a build.